# Custom In App Keyboard in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to create a custom OnScreen keyboard in UWP. It need to be part the application because it will be used on Large Table or Board devices so full control of the keyboard placement is very important (rotation on the table).

In WPF, I already made a custom keyboard like this by creating a keyboard control whith a Target Property. When a key is pressed, it raise a KeyEvent or TextComposition on the target with **UIElement.RaiseEvent(...)**.
But in UWP, there is no RaiseEvent function and it seems there is no way to raise routed event for the developper.

I want to use native Text Event (KeyDown event, TextComposition event, etc...) so solution which manually edit the Text property of TextBox ( [like this one](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/UWP-Custom-On-Screen-8fd8415e/) ) are not acceptable.

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/custom-text-input) explains how to create a control who listen to **Text Services Framework**. I think one solution would be to create a custom Text service but I didn't found any documentation on this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @DanNeely No sorry. Nothing for the moment. We are not working on UWP right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do at least part of what you were looking for using classes in the `Windows.UI.Input.Preview.Injection` namespace and the restricted `inputInjectionBrokered` capability.

This works for the `KeyUp`, `KeyDown`,  `PreviewKeyUp`, and `PreviewKeyDown` events, and as long as you don't need to send key strokes to anything outside of your app.

Non-latin scripts are outside the scope of what I'm working on, so I don't know if it can be extended to IME's which would generate TextComposition events.

Martin Zikmund demonstrates doing so [here](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2018/01/injecting-input-in-uwp-apps/), with a sample solution available on [github](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/blog-2018).

The key points are that you need to edit your `Package.appxmanifest` file (as code not via the designer) to include:

```
<Package>
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="rescap"
</Package>
```

and

```
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="inputInjectionBrokered" />
<Capabilities>
```

From there you can simulate typing and raise native key events by:

```
private async void TypeText()
{
    Input.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    //we must yield the UI thread so that focus can be acquired
    await Task.Delay(100); 

    InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
    foreach (var letter in "hello")
    {
        var info = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
        info.VirtualKey = (ushort)((VirtualKey)Enum.Parse(typeof(VirtualKey), 
                                   letter.ToString(), true));
        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { info });

        //and generate the key up event next, doing it this way avoids
        //the need for a delay like in Martin's sample code.
        info.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
        inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { info });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! finaly an awnser.
I will test this later.

Comment: @Gael if anything interesting turns up in your testing, please follow up here.  I haven't gone beyond this prototype to prove I'll be able to make a custom keyboard when the app gets to that point.  I've got a lot of other things that'll need done before getting to that point though.

Comment: You can extend this to non-latin scripts easily: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59755604/130060